# search up and show multiple entries of multi-column data in listbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search, listbox

I've seen similar cases before of this on this forum, but I've not seen an appropriate solution to my exact problem so here it goes...

Basically I have a userform with a listbox that manages data from a data table. There are multiple entires which are tied to each "entry ID" (in column A). When I search up the "entry ID" in searchbox I would like to see all the associated entries, with columns A to J for each entry, in a listbox (thus the code needs to loop through and find multiple rows, and "copy" multiple columns for each row into the listbox, which I think is where I'm struggling).

I have adopted a piece of code I've found for a similar case here on the forum, but can't seem to copy multiple columns:

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Variant
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim row_number As Integer
Dim item_in_review As Variant


Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("a")
lastrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strSearch = txtSearch.Text
    Set aCell = sht.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
         GoTo wfrefvalid
     Else
MsgBox "Oops! That Work File does not exist. Please try again.", Title:="Try again"
txtSearch.Value = ""
        End If
    Exit Sub

wfrefvalid:
row_number = 3
'clears the listbox so that you have dont have a continuously growing list
lstSearch.Clear
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = sht.Range("A" & row_number)
If item_in_review = txtSearch.Text Then
lstSearch.AddItem sht.Range("A" & row_number & ":J" & row_number)

End If
Loop Until item_in_review = ""

End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the correct way of doing what I want to do but I can't find any exact similar cases to build upon.

Would be very grateful for any tips.

Edit: @braX helped me remove the runtime error (code updated) but no data is being uploaded in the listbox... Maybe I'm not referencing either the "row"-loop or the addItem function properly but not sure which of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the row number for column A:
You have this

`lstSearch.AddItem Sheets("a").Range("A:J" & row_number)`

it should look more like this

`lstSearch.AddItem Sheets("a").Range("A" & row_number & ":J" & row_number)`

Comment: thank you! I have amended my code and that at least removed the error but no data is uploaded to the listbox. The error handler recognises when an ID doesn't exist but nothing happens if an ID does exist (ie no population or anything). I guess technically you answered the specific error I was having so I'll give you an "answered" point for that but do you have any pointers on populating my listbox? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try converting the range to an array first, and then use `.List` instead of `.AddItem`   like this: 

  Dim Arr() As Variant
  Arr = Range("E6:H6")
  ListBox1.List = Arr

Comment: that sounds like a good idea. One last question: Since my array will be a varying and in some cases uncontinuous range, what syntax is best to use to add data to the array? particularly considering that the criteria will be if the ID in A matches the search criteria. I could probably take it myself from there, thanks for all your pointers.

Comment: You can use `Redim Preserve` if the bounds of the array need to change.